# Angular data binding not working inside ng-view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-routing

I am using angular JS with angular-route and ui bootstrap to build a form with dropdownlist.

My problem is thaht when I put the ui-bootstrap dropdownlist component inside an ng-view, the component is not working as supposed, whereas when I put it outside of the ng-view it is working correctly.

For me it comes from the fact that the data binding is not working well but I didn't manage to find why.

Code is more explicit than words : see here on [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/NDAY9w3XBa1cMdhydqdE?p=preview)

```
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>


  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="routeApp">
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <nav>
    <a href="#/home" class="btn btn-primary">Page d'accueil</a>
    <a href="#/contact" class="btn btn-success">Page de contact</a>
  </nav>
  <div ng-view></div>
  
  <div ng-controller='DropdownCtrl'>

    <div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
      <button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
        {{button}} <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="uib-dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
        <li role="menuitem">
          <a href="#" ng-click="change(action)" ng-repeat="action in actions">{{action}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

You will see that the Button dropdown is working well outside of the ng-view but will not work any more inside the ng-view.

Thanx in advance

Comment: Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Perhaps you could do something with that intel

Comment: What exactly you want to do?

Comment: Get rid of `bootstrap.js` it is not needed

Comment: @Jorel : I am not sure that the missing jQuery is the problem because the dropdown list is working correctly outside the ng-view so if the missing jQuery was the problem it would not work both inside and outside the ng-view

Comment: @Mohammed Dawood Ansari : I want that when I select an option of the dropdown button, the label of the button to be updated, see it works fine for the dropdownlist outside the ngview but doesn't work anymore in the dropdownlist inside the ngview

Comment: @user3414662 yes it is, because bootstrap component aren't the same as angular-ui-bootstrap component, therefore one might need to use librairies the other don't

Comment: So it is impossible to make the button dropdown list inside a ng-view?

Comment: I dont think so that it is impossible, your  $scope.change function is actually getting executed the problem that model is not getting updated

Comment: remove `#` from href of actions. Never use that in angular hash based routing unless it refers to an actual route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using `href=#` on the links. Remove the `#` and it works fine.

Since angular routing is using hash based routes the `#` is causing a route change attempt

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/cwCBGXX8EhpJJGVlJCIW?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thamk you charlietfl but this is not working even if I remove `bootstrap.js` I still have my problem which is : I want that when I select an option of the dropdown button, the label of the button to be updated